# Include plain text with asp.net

Tags: asp.net

If I want to display (include) some plain text (which is dynamic data but only changes periodically) in an asp.net web page, what is the best way to do this?

I can think of:

1. Write the text to a user control file (.ascx)
2. Use an XMLDataSoure
3. Use the #include directive

The disadvantage of 1) is that there is some compiling time every time the text of the control changes. I think 3) is deprecated in asp.net. Option 2) does not look like an efficient way to do this to me.

Comment: Does that plain text is uniform for every user, or it varies? Also, what is the periodic interval after which your dynamic data changes?

Comment: This text is the same for every user. In my case it changes weekly. The reason I mentioned 'periodical change' is that otherwise you could just as well retrieve the data from the database every time the page is loaded.

Comment: I am already using the StreamWriter class to write the text file, but I am not sure if using the StreamReader class is a better way than the ways I already mentioned. Since they do not use code. It's the same like binding data to a repeater with code, while datasource controls are designed for this particular task to do it without code.

Comment: Why aren't you using a `Session[] variable` to store the string as the string is constant for all the users.